# Sparse Table Memory Space Complexity

Tags: range-query

If we have input of size $N=13$, which represents array that has 13 element. We need in general $O(N\log{N})$ memory to store all intervals. We see that number of intervals we need in terms of power of $2^p$ is 3, so intervals is $p=3$.

**Problem**: I am not sure though why the space we need to store intervals then is $O(13\times 3)$ please?

Comment: If the input has constant size, then you need constant memory to store all intervals.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. Thanks Prof. I read elsewhere that we need $O(NlogN)$ to store all intervals, so I am not sure what does that mean please? The context was: the algorithm is about finding sparse table first and then using lowest common ancestor (LCA) second on top of sparse table.

Comment: Asymptotic notation is meaningless if you fix all parameters.